# Get the document's owner Approval before Sharing a document on SharePoint or on OneDrive with external users

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, approval-process, onedrive, ms-flow

I got a requirement from our customer, that they want to implement MS flow workflow, so when any user try to Share a document inside SharePoint or OneDrive with external users, then the user must get the document's owner approval, before the file get externally shared

So is this something we can implement in Ms flow? and how? If this can not be implemented using MS Flow then what other options we have?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't do anything.

- So far, there is no "When a file is shared" trigger in Power Automate. So it's not possible.
- You probably thought of developing Remote Event Receiver, but it's also not possible since there's no event related to a file shared or item shared. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/jj169229(v=office.15)